# how to pass component as argument?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

without a typescript, I used this array to store routes:

```
const routes= [
    {name: 'Quiz', path: '/quiz', component: () => <Quiz />},
];

export default routes;
```

But now I decided to use typescript, and I get an error:'Quiz' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Quiz'?

```
interface IRoute {
    name: string;
    path: string;
    component: () => React.ReactNode;
}

const routes: IRoute[] = [
    {name: '', path: '', component: () => <Quiz />},
];

export default routes;
```

Comment: It looks fine, let's check your editor again.

Comment: Are you using a `.ts` or `.tsx` file, it should be `.tsx` to use JSX style tags.